# Rails 5.0 with Cocoon: Issue with belongs_to inside of nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, apache-cocoon

I've got three models:

### Model P

```
has_many :svs
has_many :gs, through: svs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :svs
```

### Model SV

```
belongs_to :p
belongs_to :g
accepts_nested_attributes_for :g
```

### Model G

```
has_many :svs
has_many :ps, through: svs
```

What I need is a form for one P that contains one or more nested forms for SVs and each of these SV-forms must have another nested form for exactly one G (slim):

```
= form_for @p do |p|
        ...
        ...
        = render 'sv_form', f: p
    = p.submit
```

### sv_form

```
= f.fields_for :svs do |sv|
    `= sv.fields_for :g do |g|`
        ...
        ...
        #sv
            = render 'sv_fields', f: sv, g: g
    .links
        = link_to_add_association 'add sv', f, :svs, partial: 'sv_fields', render_options: {locals: {g: g}}
```

### sv_fields

```
.nested_fields
    = g.label :name # here is the problem: no random id for these fields
    = g.text_field :name # here also no random id
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
    ...
    ...
    = link_to_remove_association 'remove SV', f
```

This works fine as long as I save the P with one SV only.
But as soon as I add a second SV this second's SV G-name overrides the first G-name.
Inspecting the form with firebug I can see that the random ID is missing for the second G-name so the error becomes clear.
Any help appreciated...!

Comment: Is there a reason for the obfuscation of the names? Makes it very unreadable to me and very hard to reason about. Anyways, it seems to me the `g`-s are pre-existent, and should you not select from a set of existing, otherwise the `has_many :svs` makes no sense to me. Or how do you create a new 'G' for each 'SV'. Also: why do you pass `g` (now the form parameter --to confuse the russians I guess) as a local to the `link_to_add_association` --> it should be the nested g of the sv right?

Comment: Thx Nathanvda. The idea was not to distract from the problem. P=Patient, G=Gene, SV=SequenceVariation (scientific background...).

Comment: And no, the patient does not yet exist, it is created together with one or more sequence_variations each of which has one gene. And if I don't pass the gene to the link_to_add_association then I get "undefined local variable or method 'g'". It's messed up somewhere...

Comment: You did notice that in `sv_fields` you are using both `f` and `g` and this is normally not done? (as they point to two different form-objects?). Normally you would have the `fields_for :gene` inside the `sequence_variation_fields`

Comment: I already tried it that way. Putting the fields_for :gene inside of the sequence_variation_fields-partial itself won't render the form elements for gene at all. I mean they do appear for the first sequence_variation but when I click the link_to_add_association then a new form with missing gene appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[for ease of readability I will assume P=Patient, SV=SequenceVariation, G=Gene]

From the comments I understood that each SequenceVariation has a Gene, but when adding a *new* SequenceVariation no Gene is visible. We can either add a `link_to_add_association` for a gene, or assuming each sequence-variation must have a gene, prebuild one to be filled. We can do this using the `wrap_object` option of `link_to_add_association` :

```
= link_to_add_association('add sequence variation', f, :svs, wrap_object: Proc.new {|sv| sv.build_gene; sv })
```

This will make sure that each new sequence-variation will also have an initialised gene.

And then the `sv_fields` partial can be adapted as follows:

```
.nested_fields
  = f.label :name 
  = f.text_field :name
  = fields_for :gene do |g|
    = g.label :name
    = g.text_field :name
  = link_to_remove_association 'remove SV', f
```

Comment: Ha good catch. Of course I typed the code without testing. Oooops --fixed it. And glad it helped :)